# Script for moving files that are older than 5 days

Tags: bash, file, foreach, directory, mv

I'm currently working on a script that allows me to move any file thats older than 5 days into an archive folder with the same path, except for the root folder which changes.
So something like:
root/subdir1/subdir2/file to rootarchive/subdir1/subdir2/file.
It should work recursivly.

I've already tried creating a foreach for all the files of the "root" folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      mv $file ../rootarchive/"$file"
done
```

But this didn't work properly as I the mv command couldnt find the specified destination ../rootarchive/"$file".
Has anyone of you an idea how I could solve this problem?

Thx

William

Comment: ../rootarchive/ is relative to the directory you ran the script from, did you double check it exists ?
try replacing it with a full path

Comment: It would make more sense to use `-exec mv '{}' ../rootarchive/ \;` rather than piping the output of `find` to a shell loop.

Comment: You speak of _to move any file_, but your `-name` pattern covers only filenames containing a dot. So, which do you want?